# How can i load two childs components conditionally on Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-services, angular-data

Consider the following hierarchy:

```
<app-component>
    <university-component></university-component>
    <highSchool-component></highSchool-component>
</app-component>
```

And a dialog component (dialog-component) that display at the opening app-component contains 2 choices ( university and high School :

```
<form nz-form [nzLayout]="'inline'" [formGroup]="validateForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
      <h3> Please select your academic level </h3>
            <nz-form-control [nzErrorTip]="getErrorTip('studentLevel')">
              <nz-radio-group [(ngModel)]="radioValue" formControlName="studentLevel" nzButtonStyle="solid" nzSize="small">

                  <input type="radio" name="radio3" id="university" (change)="setRouter(2)">
                      <label class="universite-label four col" nzValue="universite" for="universite">University</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="radio3" id="highSchool" (change)="setRouter(1)">
                      <label class="lycee-label four col" nzValue="lycee" for="lycee" >High School</label>

              </nz-radio-group>
            </nz-form-control>
            
       <div>
       <label nzType="flex" nzJustify="center" nzAlign="middle" nz-radio-button (click)="changeRoute()" mat-dialog-close >GO</label>
       </div>

</form>
```

How Can I if I chose University the app-component load university-component and if I chose high School the the app-component load highSchool-component

Comment: ... not sure getting the question right ... you have `radioValue` prop (ngModel-) bound in your component => so `<app-componnet> <university-component *ngIf="radioValue === 'someValOfNzRadioGroupValue'></university-component> <highSchool-component *ngIf="radioValue === 'someOhterValOfNzRadioGroupValue'></highSchool-component>` ...

Comment: magic if it will work fine (using mgModel with formControlName)

Comment: @Vovan_Super I tried this solution but it didn't work  ! because the dialog which contains radiValue is a separate component

Comment: @НикитаСереда yes works fine ... https://ibb.co/XJWbbD5

Answer (score 2):

I think you already have `radioValue` bound to `ngModel`, so you can do the following, assuming that `AppComponent` has access to `radioValue`

```
<app-component>
  <university-component *ngIf="radioValue === 'universityComponentVal'"> </university-compnent>
  <high-school-component *ngIf="radioValue === 'highSchoolVal'"></high-school-component>
</app-component>
```

If the number of conditionally rendered components increase, you may want to use `ngSwitch` and `ngSwtichCase`
https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitchCase

Comment: The dialog which contains radioValue is a separate component, how can i call it ?

Comment: You can pass it as input from AppComponent if its child component, but if we need to update the parent compenent, we can pass it via event emitter

Answer (score 0):

I believe `ngIf` is the easy way out here, instead I would recommend using routes, that is unless there are shared variables with the parent component. This would also allow for deep linking in the future so that your users may avoid needing to select a value every time.

```js
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  ... Any other routes you have
  {
    path: 'university',
    component: UniversityComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'highSchool',
    component: HighSchoolComponent
  }
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And you can either go to that route from the html using the `routerLink` directive from angular, or from the current function being called on the form.

```js
@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {
  radioValue: 'university' | 'highSchool';
 
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  changeRoute() {
    this.router.navigate([this.radioValue]);
  }
}
```

It looks like you are also uning `formControlName` with `ngModel`, this can cause errors. the above method is using the `ngModel` value, you can use the form value by accessing your form value just the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers,

I found the solution.
I created a service "level.service.ts"  :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LevelService {

  isUniversity: boolean = true;

  constructor() { }

  highScool() {
    this.isUniversity = false;
  }

  universite() {
    this.isUniversity = true;
  } 
}
```

and in app-component :

```
<app-component>
    <university-component *ngIf="levelService.isUniversity"></university-component>
    <highSchool-component *ngIf="!levelService.isUniversity"></highSchool-component>
</app-component>
```

and I added in dialog.component.html two (click) :

```
<form nz-form [nzLayout]="'inline'" [formGroup]="validateForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
      <h3> Please select your academic level </h3>
            <nz-form-control [nzErrorTip]="getErrorTip('studentLevel')">
              <nz-radio-group [(ngModel)]="radioValue" formControlName="studentLevel" nzButtonStyle="solid" nzSize="small">

                  <input type="radio" name="radio3" id="university" (change)="setRouter(2)">
                      <label class="universite-label four col" nzValue="universite" for="universite" (click)="university()">University</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="radio3" id="highSchool" (change)="setRouter(1)">
                      <label class="lycee-label four col" nzValue="lycee" for="lycee" (click)="highSchool()">High School</label>

              </nz-radio-group>
            </nz-form-control>
            
       <div>
       <label nzType="flex" nzJustify="center" nzAlign="middle" nz-radio-button (click)="changeRoute()" mat-dialog-close >GO</label>
       </div>

</form>
```

and in dialog.component.ts :

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { UniversityService } from 'src/app/services/university.service';
// others import

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog-video',
  templateUrl: './dialog-video.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog-video.component.css']
})

export class DialogVideoComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() radioValue = 'college'

  isUniversity: string = 'universite';

  // constructor() { } 
 
 // other logics

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.universityService.isUniversity = this.radioValue;
    this.universityService.collegeLycee(),
    this.universityService.universite()
  }

  highSchool() {
    this.universityService.collegeLycee();
  }

  university() {
    this.universityService.universite();
  }

}
```